# How to add a Maven project as dependency in another maven project and make live changes to it instead of JAR dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, maven-dependency-plugin

I tried to find a lot of answers but could not find any which works as expected. So posting here. It can be a possible duplicate but unable to find any right answers.

Let's consider `project A` as my maven project and `Project B` as `EclipseLink JAXB/Moxy` library code. I am using `Intellij IDE` for my application.

I have a `(My JAXB Project) Project A` which is using the 3rd party library `Eclipselink Moxy (Project B)` and I believe `Project B` has some issue due to which `Project A` is not providing the output as expected. I would like to `debug Project B` to find the issue.

So I have downloaded the [source code from `Github`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink) for the `Project B`. Now I would like to include this `Project B code` from this `local` as my `maven dependency` in my `Project A`.

I know I can create a `JAR` for `Project B` using the `mvn clean install -Dskiptests` and include that `JAR` in my `Project A` but I would like to make few changes during the `debug`. As of now, if I make any changes to `Project B` then every time I need to create the `JAR`. The library files are very huge and it has many `modules and submodules` due to which it takes a lot of time (around 5-10 mins). Also, I am unable to edit the `class file` within `JAR` so need to edit the class file of `Project B` again to create JAR, and again add it to the `project A`. This is too much of a task and waiting time.

Hence, I want to know how can I add the `Project B` directly from `local` so that I do not have to create `JAR` every time and make changes to `project B` and see the changes updated directly when I run the `Project A`.

I tried a lot of things since yesterday but nothing seems to work till now so thought of asking the same.

In short, all I want to do is:
Add the dependency from `local project` so when I click on the source for my code I can open the `class file` from my `local project` because opening the `class file` from `JAR` does not provide me an option to edit.

Comment: In Eclipse you can do that. It is called "Workspace Resolution" and part of the m2e plugin.

Answer (score 0):

- Change version in main `pom.xml` of `Project B` to one which is not there in you repo.
- install `Project B` using `install -U` command.
- Use the custom version of `Project B` in `Project A`. You can also put break point now in workspace of `Project A` to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a multi module project in Intellij.

First create a maven project for project A in Intellij, then you can add Project B as an additional module in the same project.

This way you would be able to debug and hot replace the code of Project B as well.

Help related to adding a module can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html).